# Struts 2 Validation clearing out url parameter

Tags: java, struts2

If I am at `http://foo.bar?fooId=123` and the validation fails (validate method in action class) I get redirected to `http://foo.bar` without the `fooId` param. This causes form fields to lose their values. Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `GET` to send your parameters, server on validation failure is sending you the same input page, instead of `GET` use `POST` and everything should work fine.

Your configuration would look like this :

`<result name="input">inputPage.jsp</result>` which discards any parameter that you submitted.

Also note as per [HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) `GET` shouldn't be called if operation will result in any updatation, instead `POST` should be used.